# How to save the just created Excel Workbook using VBScript?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm new to VBScript and have to import a fixed width file into Excel and Save it.
Everything works until it comes to saving it.
I'm trying to do

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWB = objExcel.ActiveWorkbooks
objWB.SaveAs("path\to\folder\outputTest1")
```

Everytime I try to launch it, I get following Error:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method: 'objExcel.ActiveWorkbooks'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Thanks to [Simoco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3067523/simoco) I fixed this problem, but now I get this Error:

```
Object Required: 'objWB'
```

Allthough I already Set it...
Here's my full code:

```
Const xlFixedWidth = 2

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWB = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook
objWB.SaveAs("I:\Zd\Zdik\SwitchMacAdd_Scripts\excel_output\outputTest1")
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = false
objExcel.Visible = True

objExcel.Workbooks.OpenText _
"I:\Zd\Zdik\SwitchMacAdd_Scripts\output_raw\output.txt",,,xlFixedWidth,,,,,,,,,Array(Array(0,1),Array(4,1),Array(22,1), Array(34,1))
```

Comment: `.ActiveWorkbooks` --> `.ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: `Allthough I already Set it...` - yes, but in *new instance* of `Excel.Application` there is no active workbooks, `Set objWB = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook` returns `Nothing`. 1) or open workbook using `Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\test.xlsx")` or 2) use `Set objExcel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")` to get already opened instance of `Excel.Application`

Comment: Do I have to `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` before I can call `GetObject(,"Excel.Application")`?

Comment: no, but you could use `GetObject(,"Excel.Application")` only if you have already opened instance of `Excel.Application` (say, you have opened any workbook)

Comment: I tried to call `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` by itself and I get Errors. Can't I call it just like this?

Comment: no, you should assign it to a variable. Use `Set objExcel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")`

Comment: When trying to do so `Set openExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") ` and call `openExcel` It says `Object doesn't support this property or method: 'objExcel.ActiveWorkbooks'`

Comment: again, change `.ActiveWorkbooks` --> `.ActiveWorkbook`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say you have this fixed width file:

20140623112524TXT[rest of the line]

The 1st field is a date in format YYYYmmdd, starting at column 0 length 8

The 2nd field is a number, starting at column 8 length 6

The 3rd field is a text, starting at column 14, length 3

To convert this to excel and save the excel using vbscript you can:

```
Const xlGeneralFormat = 1
Const xlTextFormat = 2
Const xlYMDFormat  = 5
Const xlYDMFormat=8
Const xlSkipColumn = 9

Const xlFixedWidth = 2

Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

oExcel.Workbooks.OpenText [infilename],,[fstline],xlFixedWidth,,,,,,,,, _
    Array(  Array(0, xlYMDFormat),Array(8, xlGeneralFormat),Array(14, xlTextFormat))


oExcel.Visible = True
oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs [outfilename]
```

**[infilename]** is the file to process

**[fstline]** is the 1st line to process

**[outfilename]** is the name of the excel file.

Read this to know more about data types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221100(office.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the above is your full code then you need to `Dim objWB`, and `Dim objExcel` As these should be declared before you assign something to them, also adding `Option Explicit` to the top of the code may help to give better error messages i.e. "Variable is not defined"

Comment: Looks like that was what I needed but now I get this Error: `Object Required ` It Refers to the Line under: `Const xlFixedWidth = 2`